# Protractor e2e testing Maximum limit for Multiuser testing

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am writing e2e test cases for my Angular application using protractor.I am trying to generate HTML Reports and multiuser testing. This is my

**conf.js :**

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var reporter=new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: '/test/e2e/JasmineReporter', // a location to store screen shots.
    docTitle: 'Report',
    docName:    'protractor-demo-tests-report.html'
});

exports.config = {
      seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4441/wd/hub',   
      multiCapabilities: [{
            browserName: 'chrome',
            acceptSslCerts: true,
            trustAllSSLCertificates: true,
            specs: ['first_spec.js']
        }, {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            acceptSslCerts: true,
            trustAllSSLCertificates: true,
            specs: ['second_spec.js']
        }],

      maxSessions: 1,    //Limits max number of instances

      onPrepare: function() {
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
      },       
      jasmineNodeOpts: {
            showColors: true,
            defaultTimeoutInterval: 50000
      }      
};
```

Now, it is working fine. It is generating HTML Reports for two specs.
But when I limit the instances using `maxSessions: 1` (It opens one browser at a time). It is generating report for last spec. And what is the max number of instances we can run.